# Using VQMod offset properly

Tags: php, xml, offset, opencart

I am creating a small VQMod for OpenCart

I want to search for a piece of code with mulitple lines however I can't figure out the right offset value to do so.

I was reading the vqmod manual and they recommend you count the ammount of lines then subtract the number of lines by 1 to determine the offset however it doesn't work for me?

Here is my code

```
<modification>

    <id>xxx</id>
    <version>xxx</version>
    <vqmver>xxx</vqmver>
    <author>xxx</author>

    <file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/account/register.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="replace" offset="17"><![CDATA[
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $entry_company; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="company" value="<?php echo $company; ?>" class="large-field" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="company-id-display">
          <td><span id="company-id-required" class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_company_id; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="company_id" value="<?php echo $company_id; ?>" />
            <?php if ($error_company_id) { ?>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $error_company_id; ?></span>
            <?php } ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tax-id-display">
          <td><span id="tax-id-required" class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_tax_id; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="tax_id" value="<?php echo $tax_id; ?>" />
            <?php if ($error_tax_id) { ?>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $error_tax_id; ?></span>
            <?php } ?></td>
        </tr>
        ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[ 
            <?php echo 'test'; ?>
        ]]></add>
        </operation>            
    </file>     


</modification>
```

I counted 18 lines and set my offset to 17.

Am I going wrong somewhere.

Will be great to hear back from you all
Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vqmods offset value is for replacing a line and the following x lines, however the search is for one line only. Vqmod doesn't match multiple lines

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for your answer  do you know if there is a way I can replace that whole section of code then? Thanks

Comment: Before that, can you explain what it is you're trying to achieve there, as there may be a better way of doing what you are trying to achieve. I use vQmod daily (and rewrote it for the 2.0 release), and I don't remember the last time I needed to use offset to replace a large amount of code

Comment: Hi Jay,  I figured it out,  I thought the offset was the amount of lines you tried to search, but it is the lines that follow after your search.  Thanks